# Why realm create default.realm file if in configuration file is another name

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm

Why `Realm` is using default parameters of the database despite of the configuration.

Name of the `default.realm` file should be `custom.realm` and it should be encrypted with key.

This is my configuration.

```
static func getDbConfiguration() -> Realm.Configuration {
        var configuration =  Realm.Configuration()
        configuration.encryptionKey = getKey()
        configuration.fileURL = getDbPath()
        return configuration
}
```

And each time i am requesting some interaction with Realm i am calling it like this.

```
class func delete(){
        let realm = try! Realm(configuration: getDbConfiguration())
        try! realm.write() {
            realm.deleteAll()
        }
}
```

This is app folder in iphone file explorer.

[image]

Comment: what does `getDbPath()` return?

Comment: @Dmitry file:///Users/oleg.gordiichuk/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/62631A43-C2E3-4E0B-A6D3-3A7D9342EF0E/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/C38D4EE4-E8B5-412E-9724-28841F53F8FE/custom.realm

Comment: @Dmitry also why default.realm contains same data that is in custo‌​m.realm

Comment: Make sure you always use this configuration when you create realm instances. By default Realm uses DefaultConfiguration if you don't specify any. And consider to set your configuration as default if you use it everywhere in your app. I'll allow you to use realm simply like `let realm = try! Realm()`.

Comment: @Dmitry by default each request to Realm instance is with configuration data but I am wondering why Realm save same data to default.realm?

Comment: With the code you've provided it's hard to say what went wrong but it looks like in some reason Realm is using its default configuration instead. Try to set a default configuration manually like `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = getDbConfiguration ` and see if it helps.